# MySQL and/or, everything goes

Tags: mysql

This must be a common question, but I have not found an answer yet. I have a field in the db which has a json string of selected days of the week (in dutch):

```
{ "ma":"", "di":"", "wo":"", "do":"", "vr":"", "za":"", "zo":"" }
```

Now I want to query it. So I did:

```
SELECT * FROM bla 
WHERE (daysofweek LIKE "%ma%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%di%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%wo%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%do%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%vr%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%za%" 
OR daysofweek LIKE "%zo%")
```

This obviously works if you your clients only have selected 1 day. It does however obviously not work when selecting multiple.

Now I could make a dreary long if statement for this, but there is probably a way better sollution.

Keep in mind though that the query is already in a right join on quite big tables. So complicated answers are probably not going to work due to load.

Comment: What does `daysofweek` store? Delimiter-separated data? Or single week day? Or what?

Comment: daysofweek stores the json string

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you picked here, with JSON string with multiple values in same field is the root cause of your problem.

Why do not you normalize it. Why do not you split to another table with foreign key with primary table to keep user selected day choices as independent rows. Then you will get a better, logical and SQL based solution.

Comment: Well, your comment sounds logical. But like I stated, it is already a long query with a high load. So passing in another select or join or whatever is not logical in this case.